# Encoding error in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, encoding, pandas, non-ascii-characters

In pandas dataframe, when writing to csv you can encode a file easily by adding a argument `encoding='utf-8'`

However there is an issue with this. If you are getting data directly from a database and placing it directly into a dataframe, when writing the csv, even with encoding you get an error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 24-25: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So really some decoding/encoding needs to happen prior to placing the data into a datframe.

Does anyone have a simple solution to this?

Comment: Maybe when you read the database you need to specify an encoding. I had that issue several times.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating a DataFrame from a database, you can use [`read_sql`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.sql.read_sql.html):

```
df = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM foo', con)
```

*Here con is a connection object, e.g. created using sqlite3 or mysqldb.*